# What is the intellij idea shortcut to replace value of final variable with its value?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to see the value of a final variable as shown in the image below. Is there any shortcut for this?

[image]

I want the above variable to change to the one as shown in the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fold Selection** / **Remove region** in your Keymap settings.

The default shortcut on Windows is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

This behavior is also controlled by Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Folding | **I18n strings** (make sure it's enabled).